# Failed to run torchinfo when adding ReLU layer

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following (simple) model:

```
def GetModel():   
    oModel            = nn.Sequential(       
        nn.Conv2d(3,  32 , 3, padding=1, bias=False, stride=2), nn.BatchNorm2d(32),     nn.Dropout2d(0.2),       
    )
           
    return oModel
```

I can view the model with `torchinfo` with no problem.
When I add `ReLU` layer to the model I'm getting error.

The model with `ReLU` layer:

```
def GetModel():   
    oModel            = nn.Sequential(       
        nn.Conv2d(3,  32 , 3, padding=1, bias=False, stride=2), nn.BatchNorm2d(32),  nn.ReLU(),   nn.Dropout2d(0.2),       
    )
    
       
    return oModel

torchinfo.summary(GetModel(), (128, 3, 224, 224))
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchinfo/torchinfo.py:296, in forward_pass(model, x, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, device, mode, **kwargs)
    295 if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
--> 296     _ = model.to(device)(*x, **kwargs)
    297 elif isinstance(x, dict):

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1110, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1108 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111 # Do not call functions when jit is used

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py:141, in Sequential.forward(self, input)
    140 for module in self:
--> 141     input = module(input)
    142 return input

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1128, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1126     input = bw_hook.setup_input_hook(input)
-> 1128 result = forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1129 if _global_forward_hooks or self._forward_hooks:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/activation.py:98, in ReLU.forward(self, input)
     97 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
---> 98     return F.relu(input, inplace=self.inplace)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:1442, in relu(input, inplace)
   1441 else:
-> 1442     result = torch.relu(input)
   1443 return result

RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [54], in <cell line: 9>()
      2     oModel            = nn.Sequential(       
      3         nn.Conv2d(3,  32 , 3, padding=1, bias=False, stride=2), nn.BatchNorm2d(32),  nn.ReLU(),   nn.Dropout2d(0.2),       
      4     )
      7     return oModel
----> 9 torchinfo.summary(GetModel(), (128, 3, 224, 224))

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchinfo/torchinfo.py:217, in summary(model, input_size, input_data, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, col_names, col_width, depth, device, dtypes, mode, row_settings, verbose, **kwargs)
    210 validate_user_params(
    211     input_data, input_size, columns, col_width, device, dtypes, verbose
    212 )
    214 x, correct_input_size = process_input(
    215     input_data, input_size, batch_dim, device, dtypes
    216 )
--> 217 summary_list = forward_pass(
    218     model, x, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, device, model_mode, **kwargs
    219 )
    220 formatting = FormattingOptions(depth, verbose, columns, col_width, rows)
    221 results = ModelStatistics(
    222     summary_list, correct_input_size, get_total_memory_used(x), formatting
    223 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchinfo/torchinfo.py:305, in forward_pass(model, x, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, device, mode, **kwargs)
    303 except Exception as e:
    304     executed_layers = [layer for layer in summary_list if layer.executed]
--> 305     raise RuntimeError(
    306         "Failed to run torchinfo. See above stack traces for more details. "
    307         f"Executed layers up to: {executed_layers}"
    308     ) from e
    309 finally:
    310     if hooks is not None:

RuntimeError: Failed to run torchinfo. See above stack traces for more details. Executed layers up to: [Conv2d: 1, BatchNorm2d: 1]
```

Extra details:

```
torch==1.11.0
torchinfo==1.6.6
torchvision==0.12.0+cu113

python 3.8

CUDA Version: 11.4
```

Why it's happening? How can I solve it ?

Comment: Did you happen to transfer your model on your cuda device?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this line:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.

If you want to use `cpu`, pass in `device="cpu"` into the `summary()` function:

```
torchinfo.summary(GetModel(), (128, 3, 224, 224), device="cpu")
```